# How to make wrap content for ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to make dialog with form input fields and when i use with column content is fit to screen but when i try to type values it hiding the below input fields and submit button.Show to solve this issue i only know one soluction that replacing column with listview and works it allow me to scrool but the content is not fit to screen. 
How to make the content in listview fit to sceen?
Here is my full code

```
import 'package:devaayanam/Confi.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BookPujaDialogContent extends StatefulWidget {
  BookPujaDialogContent({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BookPujaDialogContentState createState() => _BookPujaDialogContentState();
}

class _BookPujaDialogContentState extends State<BookPujaDialogContent> {
  final _formKey =GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(

      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: Confi.TEMPLENAME
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter '+Confi.TEMPLENAME;
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: Confi.DEITY
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter '+Confi.DEITY;
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: Confi.BN
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter '+Confi.BN;
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: Confi.STAR
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter '+Confi.STAR;
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: RaisedButton(

                onPressed: () {
                  // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                  // otherwise.
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                    Scaffold.of(context)
                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                  }
                },
                textColor: Colors.white,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: <Color>[
                        Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                        Color(0xFF1976D2),
                        Color(0xFF42A5F5),

      ],
      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
                  ),
                 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                 height: 40,
                 // padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 10, 45, 10),
                  child:  Center(
                    child: Text(
                        Confi.BOOKNOW,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )



          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `shirinkWrap: true` in `ListView`.

```
Dialog(
  child: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true, //TODO: Use this
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: Confi.TEMPLENAME),
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please enter ' + Confi.TEMPLENAME;
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
        ....
        ....
```